# Aligning list items to a certain x-position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a profile page with roles and names in a line but every name is a different length, so they are obviously not aligned. I tried to get them together with `px`, `em`, and `%` but I can't figure out a good solution. 
[image]

```
<div id="container-box">
    <div id="left-box">
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Frank Sinatra</strong></li>
            <li><strong>Owner / Web Master</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">
        <img src="~/images/frank.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container-box">
    <div id="left-box">
        <ul>
            <li><strong>john smith</strong></li>
            <li><strong>Administrator</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">
        <img src="~/images/john.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left-box
{
    float:left;
    font-size:16px !important;
    width:600px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-right:80px;
}
#left-box li{
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:80px;
    font-size:20px;
}

#left-box ul{
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

#left-box p 
{
    padding-top:20px;
}
#right-box
{
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#container-box{
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #DFDFDF;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding:15px;
}
#right-box img
{
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7tRPr/)***

I would suggest changing your lists to be inline blocks and use a min-width property on them

```
#left-box li{
 display:inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding-left:0;
 min-width:160px;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a few ways you can do that, if you're not constricted to using a UL for those, I would reccomend just using divs and assigning them to a width and floating them right.... example here:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 200px;"><strong>Frank Sinatra</strong></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 200px;"><strong>Owner / Web Master</strong></div>
```

It will then just keep everything at a certain width no matter what you put in each div.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left-box ul li{
    display:inline-block;/*should be inline-block*/
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:80px;
    font-size:20px;
    width: 200px; /*assign a fixed width*/
}
```